# Does calling java create new JVM instance or just another Java process?

Tags: java, jvm

Whenever we start a Java program:

```
java Herpyl.java -derp
```

Is this creating another *JVM instance*, or another Java process on top of the same JVM instance? I'm confused as to the relationship between JVM and "Java" or a "Java process". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each java invocation starts its own JVM.

Sharing one JVM between processes has problems wrt security and stability: If one process kills the JVM you also killed the other and the other process really shouldn't be able to read/modify the data of the other process without the right rights (don't forget you can call arbitrary JNI code from your java process).

If you're worried about memory consumption: Yes that does indeed increase the memory, but any modern OS will map different dlls and other things - on my win7 x64 machine an idle javaw process has a private workingset of ~300kb.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> The java tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a
>   Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that
>   class's main method

And the Java Runtime Environment includes the Java Virtual Machine and other components (like libraries) required to execute Java Applications.